the number of homeomorphisms of sphare $S^{2n}$ without a fixed point
Let $S^{2n}$ be the unit sphare of dimension $2n$, and $\pi$ be the set of all homeomorphisms of $S^{2n}$ without a fixed point. Does $\pi$ have at most $2$ elements?
I know the antipodal map $r: S^{2n}\to S^{2n}, x\mapsto -x$ is a homeomorphism without a fixed point, so $r\in \pi$. But I don't know others.

I tried to consider the deg of the homeomorphisms.
1.If $f$ is a homeomorphism of $S^{2n}$, then $\mathrm{deg} f=\pm1$.
2.If $f$ is a homeomorphism of $S^{2n}$ with $\mathrm{deg}f=1$, then f has a fixed point.
But I don't know what conditions infers non-fixed point.

For all $m > 0$ the set $\pi$ of all homeomorphisms of $S^m$ without a fixed point has infinitely many elements.
The following is well-known (and intuitively clear):

Let $D^m$ be the closed unit disk in $\mathbb R^m$. For each $a \in D^m$ with $\lVert a \rVert < 1$ there exists a homeomorphism $h_a : D^m \to D^m$  such that $h_a(0) = a$ and $h(x) = x$ for all $x \in S^{m-1}$.

We can split $S^m$ into the upper hemisphere $S^m_+ = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_{m+1}) \mid x_{m+1} \ge 0 \}$ and the lower hemisphere $S^m_- = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_{m+1}) \mid x_{m+1} \le 0 \}$ which intersect in the equator $S^{m-1} \times \{0\}$. The projection $p : \mathbb R^{m+1} \to \mathbb R^m, p((x_1,\ldots,x_{m+1})) = (x_1,\ldots,x_m)$, restricts to homeomorphisms $p_\pm : S^m_\pm \to D^m$.
For each $a \in D^m$ with $\lVert a \rVert < 1$ we get a homeomorphism $h'_a = p_-^{-1} \circ h_a \circ p_- : S^m_-  \to S^m_-$ which keeps the equator fixed. The identity on $S^m_+$ and $h'_a$ can be pasted to a homeomorphism $H_a : S^m \to S^m$.
Let $R : S^m \to S^m$ denote the antipodal map (which does not have a fixed point). Then also the maps $R_a = R \circ H_a$ are homeomorphisms without a fixed point:
$R_a$ is the antipodal map on $S^{m-1} \times \{0\}$ and maps the open upper [lower] hemisphere to the open lower [upper] hemisphere.

Thanks for your example.

Well I think the answer would be no: $\pi$ could have more then two elements take $S^2$ as an example. The antipodal map $r\circ i$, where $i:S^2\to S^2$ a homeomorphism also a homeomorphism. Here we chose $i$ to be a homeomorphism such that no $i(x)\neq -x\quad \forall x\in S^2$, then $r\circ i$ also has no fixed point. You could easily see there is inifinite many such $i$. For example I just fix one diametral line and rotate the sphere.

You are right. And this is an intuitive example.
